# Unable to get the searched document using Lucene.net

Tags: c#, .net, indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I'm new to Lucene.net. I've a situation where I need to search the all the documents in a folder for a keyword that has been entered by the user.

I've indexed all the files in the folder and prepared a query for the keywords entered by the user and performed searching.

The problem is I could get the hits and when I tried to iterate the hits, I couldn't get the fields from the documents of the hits.

Here is my code.

```
public void Searching()
{
   Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(luceneVersion.Version.LUCENE_29);
   QueryParser parser = new QueryParser(luceneVersion.Version.LUCENE_29, "content", analyzer);
   Query query = parser.Parse(txtSearchText.Text);

   Directory directory = FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(txtIndexPath.Text.Trim()));
   Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(IndexReader.Open(directory, true));
   TopScoreDocCollector collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true):
   searcher.Search(query, collector);
   ScoreDoc [] hits = collector.TopDocs(). ScoreDocs;

   foreach (ScoreDoc hit in hits)
   {
      int id = hit.Doc;
      float score = hit.Score;

      Document doc = searcher.Doc(id);

      string content = doc.Get("content");  // null
   }
}
```

When tried to debug, the content I'm getting is null, empty.

Am I missing anything in my code, this is literally bogging me since half day all the way. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying this everything whatever I could do. The problem is I've been indexing without storing the id field of the document in the index file.

Here was the code I've used while indexing.

```
doc.Add(new Field("id", id, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
```

While it should be like the following, so that it will be available in the index file.

```
doc.Add(new Field("id", id, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
```